# How to set the browser window size according to D3JS graph?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to set my browser window size according to height and width of my D3JS graph.
As some of my graph is invisible.
The code is given below where I am setting height and width.

```
var w = 1345, h = 1000;
var svg = d3.select(".graphContainer").append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);
```

Comment: It's much easier to adjust the graph to the size of the window, than the other way around.

Comment: Please do not attempt to move, resize, maximize, minimize or otherwise mess with a user's browser window.  Even if you could reliably do this, it's just annoying.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and use [`window.resizeTo(w, h)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) but it won't work reliably cross-browser (it actually *won't* work most of the time). There isn't a reliable way to resize browser windows using javascript.

Are you assigning `w` and `h` to these values because your graph needs to be exactly that big ? If your graph can fit in different dimensions, you could instead initialize `w` and `h` based on the browser window size with something like

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
```

If you're looking to fill your div exactly :

```
var w = document.getElementsByClassName('.graph-container')[0].clientWidth;
var h = document.getElementsByClassName('.graph-container')[0].clientHeight;
```